# Error with unreported exception Exception when adding encryption code

Tags: android

I'm having this error

> Error:(27, 57) error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught
>   or declared to be thrown

on this line:

```
public String encrypted = MCrypt.bytesToHex( mcrypt.encrypt("Text to Encrypt") );
```

and tried surrounding it with try and catch but it didn't work.

```
package com.example.user.test14;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MCrypt mcrypt = new MCrypt();
public String encrypted = MCrypt.bytesToHex( mcrypt.encrypt("Text to Encrypt") );

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new MyTask().execute();
}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","1"));
        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("temp",encrypted));
        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pulse","sheri"));
        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("motion","a"));
        String link="http://192.168.0.21/insert_data.php";
        boolean success = false;
        try {

            JSONObject json = makeHttpRequest(link, "POST", params1);
            success = json.getBoolean("success");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return success;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result ) {
            Log.e("result","true");
        } else {
            Log.e("result","false");
        }
    }
}

private JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,List<NameValuePair> params) {
    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    String json = "";
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, HTTP.UTF_8), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        Log.e("json", json);
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
}
```

can anyone help please? I appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try moving it into a constructor?

Comment: @Pavan I don't know how, I'm still new to Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following constructor to your class

```
MCrypt mcrypt;
public String encrypted;
public MainActivity(){
  try{
    mcrypt = new MCrypt();
    encrypted = MCrypt.bytesToHex( mcrypt.encrypt("Text to Encrypt") );
  } catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

by replacing the two corresponding lines.

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to be inside a constructor if you want to surround it with try-catch. Or do it like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public String encrypted = bytesToHex();

    private static String bytesToHex() {
        try {
            MCrypt mcrypt = new MCrypt();
            return MCrypt.bytesToHex(mcrypt.encrypt("Text to Encrypt"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked :D